# CRUD operations in MVC 3 without using db context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need help .Actually am using ADO net with 4.0 .net framework and create a own database    using app_data in solution explorer with .mdf extension.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Crudoperations.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Crudoperations.Controllers
{
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Employee/

    EmployEntities employContext;


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var details= new EmployEntities())
        {
            return View(details.employs.ToList());
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Employee/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {

        employContext = new EmployEntities();
        employ _TempEmploy = new employ();
        _TempEmploy.Id = id;


        return View(_TempEmploy);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Employee/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Employee/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(employ objEmploy)
    {
        try
        {
            employContext = new EmployEntities();
            employContext.AddToemploys(objEmploy);
            employContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        employContext = new EmployEntities();
        employ _employ = new employ();
        //_employ = ( from Employ
        //            where ID = id) 
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, employ objEmploy)
    {
        try
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Employee/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)

    {
        employ _TempEmploy = new employ();


            return View(_TempEmploy);


    }

    //
    // POST: /Employee/Delete/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, employ objEmploy)
    {
        try
        {
            //employContext = new EmployEntities();
            //employ _TempEmploy = new employ();
            //_TempEmploy.Id = id;
            //employ _employ = employContext.Find(_TempEmploy);
            employContext.DeleteObject(objEmploy);
            employContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Delete", new { id = id, saveChangesError = true });

        }
    }

    public IView detailsModel { get; set; }
}
```

}

Actually i'm getting problem in accessing the data using ID i.e in db context there is a method "Find(id)" but there is no such type of method in Object context.what i have to do for accessing the data for edit ,details and Delete the data from database

Comment: Can you add some code samples?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for fetching by id, It will fetch the first matching object.

```
db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId== Id);
```

Hope, it may help you. Have anice day.

Comment: db is also a object of the context. you ca use context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId== Id);

Comment: can u put a piece of code, where u are working on it. Will love to help you :)

Comment: hey i use query to get the data but its not working .it showing error that database table is not there